# How to combine 2 Primary disks that live on the same physical drive

Tags: partitioning

From Disk Management. I have only one 500GB SSD:

[image: From Disk Management. I have only one 500GB SSD]

[image]

Comment: Back up your system and back it up again, before you do anything else. Murphy is everywhere.

Comment: It says you have 2 physical discs.

Comment: Is this possibly a virtual machine?

Comment: Moab is indeed correct! I had forgotten that this old Acer laptop came with a Windows 7 special cache / hybrid SSD along with the original spinning HD (which I had upgraded to an SSD) I had forgotten that after updating to Win 10, I repurposed that small 18GB soldered-on SSD to be an extra drive. Sorry -- my fault 

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten that this old Acer laptop came with a Windows 7 special cache / hybrid SSD along with the original spinning HD (which I had upgraded to an SSD) I had forgotten that after updating to Win 10, I repurposed that small 18GB soldered-on SSD to be an extra drive. Sorry -- my fault